# flash cc createjs hittest works without hit

Tags: createjs

the rect should be alpha=0.1 once the circle touches the rect . but if statement not working . it becomes 0.1 opacity without hitting

```
/* js

var circle = new lib.mycircle();
stage.addChild(circle);

var rect = new lib.myrect();
stage.addChild(rect);
rect.x=200;
rect.y=300;

circle.addEventListener('mousedown', downF);
function downF(e) {
stage.addEventListener('stagemousemove', moveF);
stage.addEventListener('stagemouseup', upF);
};
function upF(e) {

stage.removeAllEventListeners();
}
function moveF(e) {
circle.x = stage.mouseX;
circle.y = stage.mouseY;
}

if(circle.hitTest(rect))
{
  rect.alpha = 0.1;

}
stage.update();
*/
```

Comment: In this demo, the hitTest just runs one time (at the beginning). Is this the intention?

Comment: Also, what version of CreateJS are you using? The /*js */ code syntax is from a fairly old version of the CreateJS Toolkit (vs the Flash/Animate HTML5 document format which supports JavaScript code)

Comment: I updated latest hosted lib . No issue . But intension is make the code "the rect should go alpha 0.1 when circle touches it .

Comment: Note that hitTest in CreateJS is just point-based. It will tell you if a specific point hits an object. If you want shape-based collision, you will have to build it, or use something like Box2D ([demo](https://github.com/CreateJS/sandbox/tree/master/EaselJS_Box2dWeb))

Answer (score 1):

The way you have used hitTest is incorrect. The `hitTest` method does not check object to object. It takes an x and y coordinate, and determines if that point *in its own coordinate system* has a filled pixel.

I modified your example to make it more correct, though it doesn't actually do what you are expecting:

```
circle.addEventListener('pressmove', moveF);
function moveF(e) {
    circle.x = stage.mouseX;
    circle.y = stage.mouseY;
    if (rect.hitTest(circle.x, circle.y)) {
        rect.alpha = 0.1;
    } else {
        rect.alpha = 1;
    }
    stage.update();
}
```

Key points:

- Reintroduced the pressmove. It works fine.
- Moved the circle update *above* the hitTest check. Otherwise you are checking where it was *last time*
- Moved the stage update to last. It should be the last thing you update. Note however that you can remove it *completely*, because you have a Ticker listener on the stage in your HTML file, which constantly updates the stage.
- Added the `else` statement to turn the alpha back to 1 if the hitTest fails.

Then, the most important point is that I changed the hitTest to be on the rectangle instead. This essentially says: "Is there a filled pixel at the supplied x and y position *inside the rectangle*?" Since the rectangle bounds are `-49.4, -37.9, 99, 76`, this will be true when the circle's coordinates are within those ranges - which is just when it is at the top left of the canvas. If you replace your code with mine, you can see this behaviour.

So, to get it working more like you want, you can do a few things.

1. Transform your coordinates. Use localToGlobal, or just cheat and use `localToLocal`. This takes `[0,0]` in the circle, and converts that coordinate to the rectangle's coordinate space.

Example:

```
var p = rect.localToLocal(0, 0, circle);
if (rect.hitTest(p.x, p.y)) {
    rect.alpha = 0.1;
} else {
    rect.alpha = 1;
}
```

2. Don't use hitTest. Use `getObjectsUnderPoint`, pass the circle's x/y coordinate, and check if the rectangle is in the returned list.

Hope that helps. As I mentioned in a comment above, you can not do full shape collision, just point collision (a single point on an object).